# How to get an selected object or index from a select field populated from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, html, angular

This is a beginner question. Please don't shoot.

In Angular, in an HTML component, I made a select field from an array of objects.

I want to retrieve this selection using a method.

Somehow I cannot use "value" or "selectedIndex" on my getElementById method (error : TS2339: Property 'value'/'selectedIndex' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

The object

```
export class VehicleModel {
  id: number;
  brand: string;
  capacity: number;
  model: string;
  consumption: number;
  range: number;
}
```

HTML

```
  <select id="selectVehicle" (change)=setupVehicle() value="Choose a vehicle">
    <option *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles" [value]="vehicle"> {{vehicle.brand + ' ' + vehicle.model}} </option>
    <option> Choose a vehicle </option>
```

Script

```
vehicles: Array<VehicleModel> = [];
selectedVehicle: VehicleModel;
 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.populateCarSelection()
  }

  populateCarSelection(): void{
    this.vehicleService.getAllVehicles().subscribe(data => this.vehicles = data)
  }

  setupVehicle(){
    const vehicleSelection = this.document.getElementById('selectVehicle');
   // const index = vehicleSelection.selectedIndex; error : TS233
   // const vehicle = vehicleSelection.value; error : TS233
  }
```

How do you get the selection from the select field in those conditions ?

EDIT :

For those who have the same problem this is how I made it work :
The object

```
export class VehicleModel {
 public constructor(init?: Partial<VehicleModel>) {
    Object.assign(this, init);
  }
  id: number;
  brand: string;
  capacity: number;
  model: string;
  consumption: number;
  range: number;
}
```

HTML

```
  <form [formGroup]="vehicleFormGroup" (change)="selectVehicle()">
<select id="vehicle" value="Choose a vehicle" formControlName="id">
    <option value ="" disabled> Choose a vehicle </option>
    <option *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles" [ngValue]="vehicle"> {{vehicle.brand + ' ' + vehicle.model}} </option>
  </select>
```

SCRIPT

```
  vehicles: Array<VehicleModel> = [];
  vehicleFormGroup: FormGroup;
  selectedVehicle;

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document, private vehicleService: VehicleService, private fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.vehicleFormGroup = this.fb.group({
      vehicle:  new FormControl(''),
    })

 ngOnInit(): void {
    this.populateCarSelection()
  }

  populateCarSelection(): void{
    this.vehicleService.getAllVehicles().subscribe(data => this.vehicles = data)
  }

 selectVehicle() {
    console.log('vehicle selected');
    this.selectedVehicle = <VehicleModel> this.vehicleFormGroup.value.vehicle;
    console.log(this.selectedVehicle)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to obtain a selection from a drop-down list. Elegant ways would be to create either a [template-driven](https://angular.io/guide/forms#building-a-template-driven-form) or a [reactive](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#reactive-forms) form.

For a quick fix, you could assign a [template reference](https://angular.io/guide/template-reference-variables) variable to the `select` tag and send it's value to the event-handler. Note that the `(change)` event-handler should be in `<select>` tag instead of the `<option>` tag.

**Template**

```html
<select 
  #vehicleSelect 
  (change)="setupVehicle(vehicleSelect.value)" 
  value="Choose a vehicle"
>
  <option> Choose a vehicle </option>
  <option *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles" [value]="vehicle"> {{vehicle.brand + ' ' + vehicle.model}}  </option>
</select>
```

**Controller**

```js
setupVehicle(vehicleSelection: VehicleModel) {
  console.log(vehicleSelection);
}
```

Again, while this may fix the issue in short-term you need to use either template-driven or reactive forms for the form to be scalable.

Also what is up with the variable `vehicle` assigned the type `VehicleModel` instead of type-definition. This might lead to other issues since there is a `[value]="vehicle"` binding in the template.

#### Update: two-way binding using `ngModel`

1. You'd actually need to bind the value using `[ngValue]` instead of `[value]`. `[ngValue]` allows other types (incl. string) to be bound to options.
2. I am aware at the moment of a property that holds the object that is bound to
   option using `[ngValue]`. So instead of using a template reference variable, you could quickly whip up a variable in the controller that can then be bound two-way to `<select>` using `ngModel`.

Try the following

**Controller**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  selectedVehicle: VehicleModel | string = "Choose a vehicle";
  vehicles: VehicleModel[] = [
    ...
  ];

  setupVehicle() {
    console.log(this.selectedVehicle);
  }
}
```

**Template**

```html
<select
  [(ngModel)]="selectedVehicle"
  (change)="setupVehicle()"
>
  <option> Choose a vehicle </option>
  <option *ngFor="let vehicle of vehicles" [ngValue]="vehicle"> 
    {{ vehicle.brand + ' ' + vehicle.model }} 
  </option>
</select>
```

Working example: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-8ed5af?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I edited the variable 'vehicle' and changed its name for selectedVehicle to avoid duplicates and changed its assignment for a type-definition.

The quick fix did not work unfortunately, the console log returns an undefined object.

Comment: I have found a solution that works and edited my initial question with the answer